# Use Peripheral object as argument of another function

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, cbperipheral

I'm very new to Swift so maybe the answer to my question will seem easy to you.
I want to create an interface to scan BLE devices, list them in a TableView, and connect to the selected device in this list.
So far, i achieved to scan and list, but i wonder how i can do to connect to the desired device you just clicked in the tableview. I assume i have to send peripheral object to tableview DidSelectRowAtIndexPath function, but i really don't know how to do this. 
Or surely there's a smarter way to do this ?
Thanks for your answers and time

Here's what i've done so far :

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITextViewDelegate  {
@IBOutlet var status: UITextView!
@IBOutlet
var manager:CBCentralManager!
var tableView: UITableView!
var items: [String] = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    status!.delegate = self
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return self.items.count; }
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    status.text = "Connexion en cours";
    self.manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil) // HERE IS THE THING...
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn {
        central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
        status.text = "Recherche d'appareil Bluetooth";
    }
    if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff { status.text = "Le Bluetooth est éteint"; }
    if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported { status.text = "Le Bluetooth n'est pas supporté"; }
    if central.state == CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized { status.text = "Le Bluetooth n'est pas autorisé"; }
}
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    items += ["\(peripheral.name)"]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.manager.stopScan()        
}
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    status.text = "Connecté au périphérique";
    //peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}
}
```

By the way, i read everywhere that CoreBluetooth was dealing with BLE. So what do i use to connect no BLE device ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you CBPeripheral items in array not name and then pass that object to connect . Some like following may fix for you.
First change this line in your didDiscoverPeripheral

```
items += ["\(peripheral.name)"]
```

to

```
items += [peripheral]
```

Then change this line in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
```

to

```
cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row].name
```

then in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
self.manager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
```

to

```
self.manager.connectPeripheral(self.items[indexPath.row], options: nil)
```